# Problem with super & overriding - better way to do this?

Tags: java, architecture, groovy

I'm having a problem in relation to using super and overriding. Basically, class `B` which extends `A` has a setter for the current state of the class. Inside the setter, depending on the value of the current state, a different event can be executed.

In the setter for `B` the first thing that happens is that it called `super` so that the setter for `A` can go launch general events. Then the control returns to the setter of `B` where I can execute specific events if needed.

The problem comes when `A` executes events that call the setter and so it can go multiple depths before returning back to to `B`.

The following code illustrates what I'm talking about (it's groovy, but that's irrelevant):

```
class A
{
    public int num = 0;
    public void setFoo( int i ) 
    { 
        println "A: $i"; 
        num = i + 1;

        // what's actually happening, is that in the setter, depending
        // on the value, an event can be executed, which will in turn
        // call setFoo() on the class. this is just the equivalet
        if( i < 3 )
            this.setFoo( num );
    }
}
class B extends A
{
    public void setFoo( int i ) 
    {
        println "B: $i - num $num";
        super.setFoo( i );
        println "After super for $i - num: $num";
    }
}

def B = new B();
B.foo = 0;
```

This results in an output of:

```
B: 0 - num 0
A: 0
B: 1 - num 1
A: 1
B: 2 - num 2
A: 2
B: 3 - num 3
A: 3
After super for 3 - num: 4
After super for 2 - num: 4
After super for 1 - num: 4
After super for 0 - num: 4
```

When I come back to `B` after the call to `super` ("After super for...") the value of `num` is always the same, meaning that it screws with what I'm trying to do in `B` (i.e. launch specific events).

Some points on the architecture to begin with:

- "Why not use `i` instead of `num` in the setter for `B`"? - This is just the easiest example to show the problem - what's actually happening in my code is different, just the same problem. In my case, I have access to `num`, not `i`. Even if I rewrote part of it to pass `i`, the state of the class will have moved on (due to the base class)
- It's a server environment, so I don't have access to a frame loop or something similar. It's event based.
- It should be possible to async execute the event, or set the event up to schedule later, but that requires a lot of advance knowledge of where and when the event is going to be used, which breaks the whole point of events in the first place

What I'm looking for is a way to launch events based on the state of the class, but have it happen after the return from `super` (while still working for the base class) if that makes any sense.

Ideas?

**EDIT**

To give a better idea of the code I'm using (based on Don's suggestion to use a callback), here is a simplified version of what I have. (If you want to run it, you can just copy it into http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/):

```
// A is our base class
​class A{
    public int currentState= 0;
    public void setCurrentState( int i ) 
    { 
        this.currentState = i;
        this._onStateChanged();
    }

    protected void _onStateChanged()
    {
        println "The state in A is $currentState";

        // depending on the state launch some events.
        // these can changed the current state of
        // B
        if( this.currentState == 0 )
        {
            def event = new MyEvent( this );
            event.execute();
        }
    }
}

// B is a more specific version of A
class B extends A
{
    protected void _onStateChanged()
    {
        println "The state in B is $currentState";
        super._onStateChanged();
        println "The state in B afterwards is $currentState";

        // launch specific events based on the current state
        if( this.currentState == 0 )
           println "Launch a specific event!";
    }
}

// simple event class that can change the status of B
class MyEvent
{
    private B b = null;
    public MyEvent( B b )
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void execute()
    {
        // do some stuff
        b.currentState++;
    }
}

// program start
def b = new B();
b.currentState = 0;​
```

`B` has to call `super` as there are some states where I want a basic *plus* a specific event. Basic events are normally used to set the program state, while specific ones are there to react.

In this example, my output is:

```
The state in B is 0
The state in A is 0
The state in B is 1
The state in A is 1
The state in B afterwards is 1
The state in B afterwards is 1
```

i.e. B never gets to react to the state being 0

**Edit**

If I change the `super()` call in `B` to the end of `_onStateChanged()` rather than the start, this will give the chance for it to react to the state before it gets changed. Is this a simple solution to this problem, or just wrong?

**Edit**
So I came up with this (again, you can copy it into the groovy console appspot site):

```
// A is our base class
class A{
    public int currentState = 0;
    public int nextState = 0;
    public boolean canChange = true;
    public void setCurrentState( int i ) 
    { 
        if( this.canChange )
        {
            this.currentState = i;
            this._onStateChanged();
        }
        else
            this.nextState = i;
    }

    protected void _onStateChanged()
    {
        println "The state in A is $currentState";

        // depending on the state launch some events.
        // these can changed the current state of
        // B
        if( this.currentState == 0 )
        {
            def event = new MyEvent( this );
            event.execute();
        }
    }
}

// B is a more specific version of A
class B extends A
{
    protected void _onStateChanged()
    {
        this.canChange = false;
        println "The state in B is $currentState";
        super._onStateChanged();
        println "The state in B afterwards is $currentState";

        // launch specific events based on the current state
        if( this.currentState == 0 )
           println "Launch a specific event!";

        this.canChange = true;
        if( this.nextState != 0 )
        {
            int state = this.nextState;
            this.nextState = 0;
            this.currentState = state;
        }
    }
}

// simple event class that can change the status of B
class MyEvent
{
    private B b = null;
    public MyEvent( B b )
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void execute()
    {
        // do some stuff
        b.currentState++;
    }
}

// program start
def b = new B();
b.currentState = 0;​
```

It gives me the desired output:

```
The state in B is 0
The state in A is 0
The state in B afterwards is 0
Launch a specific event!
The state in B is 1
The state in A is 1
The state in B afterwards is 1
```

but is kind of ugly. Better way?

Comment: That B extends A is mandatory or could you possibly change that?

Comment: nothing is mandatory :) I could take B out to it's own class, but you would lose the benefits of OO and it would involve a lot of rewriting/retesting etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have two solutions to this. This first one is the last code sample provided. It adds another parameters to check if we can change, and if so, does, otherwise it waits:

```
// A is our base class
class A{
    public int currentState = 0;
    public int nextState = 0;
    public boolean canChange = true;
    public void setCurrentState( int i ) 
    { 
        if( this.canChange )
        {
            this.currentState = i;
            this._onStateChanged();
        }
        else
            this.nextState = i;
    }

    protected void _onStateChanged()
    {
        println "The state in A is $currentState";

        // depending on the state launch some events.
        // these can changed the current state of
        // B
        if( this.currentState == 0 )
        {
            def event = new MyEvent( this );
            event.execute();
        }
    }
}

// B is a more specific version of A
class B extends A
{
    protected void _onStateChanged()
    {
        this.canChange = false;
        println "The state in B is $currentState";
        super._onStateChanged();
        println "The state in B afterwards is $currentState";

        // launch specific events based on the current state
        if( this.currentState == 0 )
           println "Launch a specific event!";

        this.canChange = true;
        if( this.nextState != 0 )
        {
            int state = this.nextState;
            this.nextState = 0;
            this.currentState = state;
        }
    }
}

// simple event class that can change the status of B
class MyEvent
{
    private B b = null;
    public MyEvent( B b )
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void execute()
    {
        // do some stuff
        b.currentState++;
    }
}

// program start
def b = new B();
b.currentState = 0;​
```

The second solution takes a more listener like approach. Both the base and the extending class register functions to call when the state changes:

```
// A is our base class
class A{
    public int currentState = 0;
    public def listeners = [];
    public void setCurrentState( int i ) 
    { 
        // call each of our listeners with the current state
        this.currentState = i;
        listeners.each { it( i ); }
    }

    public A()
    {
        this.addListener( this.&_onStateChanged );
    }

    public void addListener( def callback )
    {
        this.listeners.add( 0, callback );
    }

    protected void _onStateChanged( int state )
    {
        println "The state in A is $state";

        // depending on the state launch some events.
        // these can changed the current state of
        // B
        if( state == 0 || state == 1 )
        {
            def event = new MyEvent( this );
            event.execute();
        }
    }
}

// B is a more specific version of A
class B extends A
{
    public B()
    {
        super();
        this.addListener( this.&_onBStateChanged );
    }

    protected void _onBStateChanged( int state )
    {
        println "The state in B is $state";

        // launch specific events based on the current state
        if( state == 0 )
            println "Launch a specific event!";
    }
}

// simple event class that can change the status of B
class MyEvent
{
    private B b = null;
    public MyEvent( B b )
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void execute()
    {
        // do some stuff
        b.currentState++;
    }
}

// program start
def b = new B();
b.currentState = 0;
```

Both give me the output I'm looking for, though the second one is slightly broken, as it breaks the normal convention of adding listeners. Listeners are added to the start of the list, rather than the end. That'll give me an output like:

```
The state in B is 0
Launch a specific event!
The state in A is 0
The state in B is 1
The state in A is 1
The state in B is 2
The state in A is 2
```

So B gets called first, but at least they're in a good order. If I just push listeners to the list, I get:

```
The state in A is 0
The state in A is 1
The state in A is 2
The state in B is 2
The state in B is 1
The state in B is 0
Launch a specific event!
```

So B will get to react to the state being 0, but the order is reversed and by that stage, the state has changed to something else. It also breaks a bit in that it requires knowledge that B will never launch an event that will change the state, as otherwise we still have the same problem.

Out of the two, I think the first one is the best (assuming a non-rewrite of the architecture/problem). It's a bit more complicated, but doesn't require prior knowledge anywhere and the events get called in the right order.

Unless someone can suggest a better architecture for the problem, I'll go with that.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, `A.setFoo` is broken

```
class A
{
    public int num = 0;
    public void setFoo( int i ) 
    { 
        println "A: $i"; 
        num = i + 1;

        // what's actually happening, is that in the setter, depending
        // on the value, an event can be executed, which will in turn
        // call setFoo() on the class. this is just the equivalet
        if( i < 3 )
            this.setFoo( num );
    }
}
```

Because `new A().setFoo(2)` (for example) will cause a stack overflow. Something like the following might be a better design

```
abstract class A
{
    public int num = 0;

    abstract void setFooCallback(int i)

    public final void setFoo( int i ) 
    { 
        println "A: $i"; 
        num = i + 1;

        // what's actually happening, is that in the setter, depending
        // on the value, an event can be executed, which will in turn
        // call setFoo() on the class. this is just the equivalet
        if( i < 3 )
            this.setFooCallback( num );
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public void setFooCallback( int i ) 
    {
        // Implement me to launch custom events or whatever
        // If you call setFoo in here you'll get a stack overflow
    }
}
```

If you need to instantiate instances of A, just remove the `abstract` modifiers and change `setFooCallback` to:

```
void setFooCallback(int i) { // default implementation does nothing }
```

FYI, I think the above is an example of the Template (Method) pattern

Comment: This is almost exactly what I have at the minute (The difference being that `A` in my example isn't abstract). The code I posted was the easiest illustration of the problem (ignoring the stack overflow). The setter is in `A` which calls an `onStateChanged()` function that launches events. `B` overrides that, calls `super` etc. It still hits the same problems though

Comment: Actually, re-looking at it, the OP test run disproves the stack overflow - he starts with 0...  The moment the input parm hits 3, it prints the line, increments num, then exits (won't call `foo` again).

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that Java copies and passes all arguments by value.  With primitives (like the `int i`), this results in each method getting it's own copy of the value.  Usually, this is to protect against what you're actually trying to do, as method side-effects can otherwise surprise people.
A quick and easy way to fix this is to return the modified value of `i` - so, your call looks like this: `i = super.foo(i);`.  This has two benefits - 1) it lets people know that you expect that the value of `i` may change, and 2) you're not depending on a side-effect to change the value.
Otherwise, you could change `i` to be some sort of object wrapper (I hesitate to say `Integer`, because there are some under-the-cover optimization things that could mess this design up).  But if you do that, document the desired behaviour out the wazoo, or developers who use the method may be surprised at changing values (or future maintainers may not correctly adjust the values).

---

EDIT:
Okay, from the sound of it, you want to react to both the current *and* a previous state, **but** you never store the previous state...
Clearly, you're going to have to store off the previous state somehow - a local variable inside `b._onStateChanged()` is probably your best bet.  Otherwise, your program will continue to react to the current state (just, the current state isn't what you were expecting).
Also, you may want to change up your architecture a little - as it is, you never know if your default behaviour (inside of `A`) will still be carried out.  Look at @Don's recommendation again, as I suspect this will be more in the direction your architecture needs to go (you always want the generic, right?).  In other words, don't call the specific behaviour first - call the generic, have it perform its modifications, and have it call the specific behaviour when it's done.  If necessary, you can then also have the `setFoo()` method call itself recursively, allowing it to call `setFooCallback()` for each mutated state.

Comment: Returning a value isn't a bad idea actually. The only problem is that by the time I receive control back in `B` the state of the program could be completely different - I can't launch events based on previous states when it's no longer the case. Does that make sense?

Comment: Retrieve control back in `B` when?  It pops back into `B` every recursive loop... Do you want the original state, or the mutated state, or something in between?

Comment: See the original code ouput. The lines "After super for..." or "The state in B afterwards..." is the control coming back to `B` after the call to super. In the second example, both outputs are 1, whereas ideally it should be 0 and 1. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to solve this is using the [Template Method](http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html) design pattern.

Comment: Thanks, though as I mentioned under @Don's answere, I have something similar to the Template method at the minute, yet the base class method can't be abstract. I could make it so, but then I'd be copying a lot of the same functionality into the extending classes, which kind of belays the point have having an inheritence. If you can whip up some quick code that's better than my final example, I'd love to see it

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like you are trying to execute specific `B` events before 'default' `A` events. In this case most appropriate approach for me would be executing `B` events first, then calling `super` to trigger `A` events.

UPDATE:

Use Template Method pattern:

```
​class A{
public int currentState= 0;
public void setCurrentState( int i ) 
{ 
    this.currentState = i;
    println "The state in A is $currentState";

    // Maybe you need to split your MyEvent into two events.
    // MyEventA - Does whatever required before executing special events.
    def eventA = new MyEventA( this );
    eventA.execute();

    this._invokeSpecialEvents();

    // depending on the state launch some events.
    if( this.currentState == 0 )
    {
        // MyEventB - Does whatever required after executing special events (do actual currentState change).
        def event = new MyEventB( this );
        event.execute();
    }
}

protected void _invokeSpecialEvents()
{
    // You mentioned that cannot make A class abstract.
    // This method is empty rather than abstract only for that reason.
}
```

}

Comment: technically `A` should get called before `B` - it just looks the other way because of how the `println` statements are coming out. I moved the `super()` call to the end of `B`'s override function, and I thought I had it working, but I found in some situations it was giving me gyp with the event order.

Comment: @divillysausages You should consider your events as some kind of transactions. It seems you leek isolation between your events. Your events should be executed one after the other. When any event is completed - the object is in consistent state, and this state is input state for next event. Just think what operations (transaction) and in which order you would like to run and implement template method pattern accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the code example. I can't really break up MyEvent into two parts, so this will give me the same output as moving the `super()` call to the end of `B`'s override function.

Comment: *"Your events should be executed one after the other... is input state for next event."* I think that's roughly what I have in the first example in my answer (the answer I submitted, not the question). It checks if we can move on to the next stage before doing so, so we get the proper order: `A:0, B:0, A:1, B:1, A:2, B:2...`. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Just to clarify a point in your answer: *"For me it looks like you are trying to execute specific B events before 'default' A events"* - I'm trying to call default `A` events before specific `B` events, however, it's the default events that move the state on

Comment: @divillysausages As how you have described, you cannot execute events one after the other. You want your MyEvent to be executed on initial state, then you want SpecialEvent to be executed, hm, again on the state of the object which was before MyEvent execution.

Comment: pretty much - i want to "hold up" the state until all events are finished. `B`'s events need to be on the current state of the program, not reacting to an old state